# jq editing JSON not changing value

Tags: json, bash, jq, edit, in-place

I have a json file that I want to manipulate; but I can't seem to get the data to change as I want.

If I execute 1; the return is "true" because the folder is paused.

```
1: jq '.folders[] | select(.label=='\"$folder\"') | .paused' "$f"
```

If I execute 2; a single record is selected and the "true" is replaced with "false".

```
2: jq '.folders[] | select(.label=='\"$folder\"') .paused = false' "$f"
```

If I execute 3; the entire file is returned but no change is made.

```
3: jq 'if (.folders[] | .label == '\"$folder\"') then .paused = false else . end' "$f"
```

I want the entire file returned with the change made so I can post it back to update the config I'm trying to change.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: could you please provide an example of the json?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use select on the label selection, otherwise the context changes and you can't return to the whole object.

```
(.folders[] | select (.label == '\"$folder\"')).paused = false
```

Also, it's cleaner to propagate the variable value as a variable into jq instead of handling or corner cases of quoting yourself:

```
jq --arg folder "$folder" '(.folders[] | select (.label == $folder)).paused = false' "$f"
```

Comment: Also please suggest avoiding `'\"$folder\"'` and use the `--arg` flag

Comment: eg ```jq --arg folderName "some-folder" '(.folders[] | select(.label==$folderName).paused) = false```. Avoids all the '\"$varname\"' which gets old quickly

Comment: Updated. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

All working now!

See: [Syncthing forum](https://forum.syncthing.net/t/pause-resume-folder-using-cli/14828/6) for more info.

I am trying to pause / resume specific folders on a schedule, using cron. This is not supported by the API yet so I needed to do it manually by editing the config.

Thanks for all the help.